# How to configure amplify-sign-up for username?

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using Amplify UI component for authentication with Angular.

For users to sign up I have:

```
<amplify-sign-up
  slot="sign-up"
  usernameAlias="username"
  [formFields]="formFields"
></amplify-sign-up>
```

Users can sign up with a username but I want this to be limited to a certain number of characters (e.g., up to 10 characters).

I tried to look at the documentation but I can't seem to find any.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much doc for angular amplify create account UI, so what you need to do is use the JS documentation. https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js

In the signUp function, you implement a function to check the username and make sure it meets your requirements.